# Firebase Realtime Database request issue with CakePHP

Tags: php, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cakephp

After recovering one of my project on Git, I realized that my CakePHP app can no longer make get requests to my Firebase Realtime Database

First of all I use the ktamas77 lib (https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php) for the communication between my CakePHP and the realtime database. I thought my problem came from the token that would have changed but no, I can't find where the problem comes from. I also specify that all the php extensions have been added and the token that I use has been retrieved in Setting -> Project Setting -> Service Account.

```
use Firebase\FirebaseLib;

const URL = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/';
const TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const PATH = '/Test/';

$getValue = $firebase->get(PATH.'/value');
```

As soon as the get request is executed it tells me that it is retrieving a boolean.